# Password Protect MS Access Report File

Tags: ms-access, report, password-protection, prompt

I'm looking to password protect a single report witihin my MS Access database. Is there a way to do this without using code? If you do use code, how do I have it such that when someone clicks the single report file, the user will be prompted for a password. BTW there are multiple reports in this one database...

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this would be to ask for the password at the report's open event.  This simple example could be a starting point:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Const cstrPassWord As String = "open"
    Dim strPassWord As String
    strPassWord = InputBox("Password:")
    If Not strPassWord = cstrPassWord Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You could refine if you want to give the user more than one chance to get the password right ... or display a message when password entered incorrectly ... or whatever else you want.

Comment: Where do i specify the password in the above code? And how do I display a message of "You have entered the incorrect password" if they enter the wrong password?

Comment: The password is declared as the constant, cstrPassWord, and its value is "open".  To display your message, include a `MsgBox` statement within the `If ... End If` code block.  You can find details about `MsgBox` from the Access on-line help topic.

Comment: No, not directly.  You could build a form based on the table and password protect the form ... but that's not what I think you're asking for now.  If you can use the older MDB instead of ACCDB db format, you could use Jet ULS (user level security) to set user/group privileges for the tables.  But ULS can be tricky to set up correctly, and the security it offers is not strong.  Of course the answer I posted isn't all that strong either.

Comment: thats good adice...for now I've created a password protected form and simply hid the table via the table properties and choosing "hidden"...i dont really need to see the table...just the form...thank you!